# Unable to rerender FlatList inside a modal

Tags: javascript, react-native, modal-dialog

*** My goal is to be able to rerender DATA upon every invocation of generateNewTicket(). However, the re-rendering happens only once I touch the ticket ***.

I tried using tryOut [I am sure in ignorance] to change the state but it did not work.

It works fine if I set modalVisible to be false and then immediately set it to be true but then the system first comes out of the modal and then I need to click to see the modal again.

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import {
  SafeAreaView,
  View,
  TouchableOpacity,
  TouchableHighlight,
  FlatList,
  StyleSheet,
  Text,
  Modal,
  Alert,
  Button,
  BackHandler,
} from 'react-native';

import Constants from 'expo-constants';
import Welcome from './Welcome';

const DATA = [
  {
    id: '11',
    title: '  ',
  },
  {
    id: '12',
    title: '  ',
  },
  {
    id: '13',
    title: '  ',
  },
  {
    id: '14',
    title: '  ',
  },
  {
    id: '15',
    title: '  ',
  },
  {
    id: '16',
    title: '  ',
  },
  {
    id: '21',
    title: '  ',
  },
  {
    id: '22',
    title: '  ',
  },
  {
    id: '23',
    title: '  ',
  },
  {
    id: '24',
    title: '  ',
  },
  {
    id: '25',
    title: '  ',
  },
  {
    id: '26',
    title: '  ',
  },
];

generateNewTicket();

Function generateNewTicket() {
    for (i=0; i < 12; i++) {
        DATA[i] = Math.floor(Math.random() * 1000)+1000}
    }

function Item({ id, title, selected, onSelect }) {
  return (
    <TouchableOpacity
      onPress={() => onSelect(id)}
      style={[
        styles.item,
        { backgroundColor: selected && title != '  ' ? 'yellow' : '#f9c2ff' },
      ]}
    >
      <Text style={styles.title}>{title}</Text>
    </TouchableOpacity>
  );
}

export default function App() {
  const [selected, setSelected] = React.useState(new Map());

  const onSelect = React.useCallback(
    id => {
      const newSelected = new Map(selected);
      newSelected.set(id, !selected.get(id));

      setSelected(newSelected);
    },
    [selected],
  );

  const [modalVisible, setModalVisible] = React.useState(true);

  return (

    <SafeAreaView style={styles.container}>
        <Text style={styles.titleText}>
            Test Program
        </Text>

      <Modal
        animationType="slide"
        transparent={false}
        visible={modalVisible}
      >
        <FlatList
          style={styles.ticketposition}
          data={DATA}
          numColumns={6}
          renderItem={({ item }) => (
            <Item
              id={item.id}
              title={item.title}
              selected={!!selected.get(item.id)}
              onSelect={onSelect}
            />
          )}
          keyExtractor={item => item.id}
          extraData={tryOut }
        />

        <TouchableHighlight
          style={{ ...styles.openButton, backgroundColor: "#2196F3" }}
          onPress={() => {
            tryOut = tryOut++;
            generateNewTicket();
          }}
        >
            <Text style={styles.textStyle}>Exit Program</Text>
        </TouchableHighlight>
      </Modal>

      <TouchableHighlight
        style={styles.openButton}
        onPress={() => {
          setModalVisible(!modalVisible);
        }}
      >

        <Button
          style={styles.primaryButton}
          title="Test Program"
          color="lightcoral"
          onPress={() => {
            setModalVisible(!modalVisible);
          }}
        />
      </TouchableHighlight>
    </SafeAreaView>
  );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    marginTop: 100,
    marginHorizontal: 15,
  },
  item: {
    backgroundColor: '#f9c2ff',
    padding: 0, //1
    marginVertical: 8,
    marginHorizontal: 1,
    width: 36, //40
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',
  },

  title: {
    fontSize: 32,
  },

  titleText: {
    fontSize: 50,
    fontWeight: "bold",
    fontSize: 20,
    marginHorizontal: 135,
    marginBottom: 20,
  },

  textStyle: {
    fontSize: 20,
    marginHorizontal: 125,
  },

  primaryButton: {
    fontSize: 30,
    padding: 20,
    marginTop: 10,
    marginTop: 50,
    color: '#c3c3c3',
    marginBottom: 20,
    width: 150,
  },

  ticketposition: {
    marginTop: 50,
    marginLeft: 20,
  },


});
```

Comment: I think your `generateNewTicket()` function should be checked. Can you please update your answer with the whole code of your `Modal` js file?

Comment: The generateNewTicket() function just generates random numbers between 1000 and 2000 and assigns to DATA. Please see below.

Comment: I've added an answer. Did you try it?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is this. You have taken `DATA` as a `const`. You are trying to change it. That's one problem. Even you define `DATA` as a `var`, the `Flatlist` is not re-rendered when you changed it. Because `React Native` does not re-render any component against the changes made on `var` or any other kind like that. But it re-render the particular component if a `state` value is changed.

So, you have to input your `data` as a `state`. When you change your `data`, you have to change and update `state`. When the `state` value is changed, it re-render the `Flatlist`

Please check the code below...

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import {
  SafeAreaView,
  View,
  TouchableOpacity,
  TouchableHighlight,
  FlatList,
  StyleSheet,
  Text,
  Modal,
  Alert,
  Button,
  BackHandler,
} from 'react-native';

import Constants from 'expo-constants';

const DATA = [
  {
    id: '11',
    title: '  ',
  },
  {
    id: '12',
    title: '  ',
  },
  {
    id: '13',
    title: '  ',
  },
  {
    id: '14',
    title: '  ',
  },
  {
    id: '15',
    title: '  ',
  },
  {
    id: '16',
    title: '  ',
  },
  {
    id: '21',
    title: '  ',
  },
  {
    id: '22',
    title: '  ',
  },
  {
    id: '23',
    title: '  ',
  },
  {
    id: '24',
    title: '  ',
  },
  {
    id: '25',
    title: '  ',
  },
  {
    id: '26',
    title: '  ',
  },
];

function Item({ id, title, selected, onSelect }) {
  return (
    <TouchableOpacity
      onPress={() => onSelect(id)}
      style={[
        styles.item,
        { backgroundColor: selected && title != '  ' ? 'yellow' : '#f9c2ff' },
      ]}>
      <Text style={styles.title}>{id}</Text>
    </TouchableOpacity>
  );
}

export default function App() {
  const [selected, setSelected] = React.useState(new Map());
  const [modalVisible, setModalVisible] = React.useState(false);
  const [data, setData] = React.useState(DATA);
  const [trigger, setTrigger] = React.useState(false);

  const onSelect = React.useCallback(
    (id) => {
      const newSelected = new Map(selected);
      newSelected.set(id, !selected.get(id));

      setSelected(newSelected);
    },
    [selected]
  );

  const generateNewTicket = () => {
    var newData = data;
    var i;
    for (i = 0; i < 12; i++) {
      newData[i] = {
        id: (Math.floor(Math.random() * 1000) + 1000).toString(),
        title: '  ',
      }
    }

    setData(newData);
    setTrigger(!trigger)
  };

  return (
    <SafeAreaView style={styles.container}>
      <Text style={styles.titleText}>Test Program</Text>

      <Modal animationType="slide" transparent={false} visible={modalVisible}>
        <FlatList
          style={styles.ticketposition}
          data={data}
          numColumns={6}
          renderItem={({ item }) => (
            <Item
              id={item.id}
              title={item.title}
              selected={!!selected.get(item.id)}
              onSelect={onSelect}
            />
          )}
          keyExtractor={(item) => item.id}
        />

        <TouchableHighlight
          style={{ ...styles.openButton, backgroundColor: '#2196F3', marginBottom: 20 }}
          onPress={generateNewTicket}>
          <Text style={styles.textStyle}>Try Out</Text>
        </TouchableHighlight>

        <TouchableHighlight
          style={{ ...styles.openButton, backgroundColor: '#2196F3' }}
          onPress={() => setModalVisible(!modalVisible)}>
          <Text style={styles.textStyle}>Exit Program</Text>
        </TouchableHighlight>
      </Modal>

      <TouchableHighlight
        style={styles.openButton}
        onPress={() => {
          setModalVisible(!modalVisible);
        }}>
        <Button
          style={styles.primaryButton}
          title="Test Program"
          color="lightcoral"
          onPress={() => {
            setModalVisible(!modalVisible);
          }}
        />
      </TouchableHighlight>
    </SafeAreaView>
  );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    marginTop: 100,
    marginHorizontal: 15,
  },
  item: {
    backgroundColor: '#f9c2ff',
    padding: 0, //1
    marginVertical: 8,
    marginHorizontal: 1,
    width: 36, //40
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',
  },

  title: {
    fontSize: 32,
  },

  titleText: {
    fontWeight: 'bold',
    fontSize: 20,
    marginHorizontal: 135,
    marginBottom: 20,
  },

  textStyle: {
    fontSize: 20,
    marginHorizontal: 125,
  },

  primaryButton: {
    fontSize: 30,
    padding: 20,
    marginTop: 50,
    color: '#c3c3c3',
    marginBottom: 20,
    width: 150,
  },

  ticketposition: {
    marginTop: 50,
    marginLeft: 20,
  },
});
```

Here, I've passed `data` as a `state`. When you call `generateNewTicket()`, it changes the `state` value of `data`. Even you change the value of `data` here, it does not re-render as it does not recognize a difference. That's sometimes happening. So, What I did is, used another `state` called `trigger` to toggle between. Now it works! Please check it...

Comment: Thank you Sennen. I am unable to make it work but I want to make sure that I am not making a mistake before getting back to you. System says "Can't find variable: data"

Comment: You are welcome! :-) BTW, I didn't get the error "Can't find variable: data". I tested it on my device. Now, it is working. Please check it...

Comment: I tried running the verbatim code as suggested by you. I get the 12 "boxes" but without any numbers.  WHen I press the Exit Program the same thing happens again.

Comment: The problem why you don't get anything inside the box is, you have put `title` instead of `id` in the `Item` I had to change it. Please just copy my answer code as a whole and then try. It's working...

Comment: It is embarrassing but no.Essentially I need to render **title** rather than **id** but I am still unable to do so.

Comment: The title is an empty string. So, how to render a title if it is empty? What do you need to display as the title?

Comment: I was blindsided by **id**s. I have modified my logic to only use *ids* and completely get rid of titles. Now everything is working fine. Thank you very much. I tried to up-vote you but my vote does not count as I am a newbie!